# Organising Data

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed

I have data file which looks like this:

```
chr1 762440 762981 SAMD11 
chr1 858932 859148 KLHL17 SAMD11 NOC2L 
chr1 859786 860145 KLHL17 SAMD11 NOC2L
chr1 890663 891747 KLHL17 NOC2L  SAMD11  HES4
```

I want to is to arrange all the names one below the other with the values in first three column.

Something like this

```
chr1 762440 762981 SAMD11 
chr1 858932 859148 KLHL17
chr1 858932 859148 SAMD11 
chr1 858932 859148 NOC2L 
chr1 859786 860145 KLHL17 
chr1 859786 860145 SAMD11 
chr1 859786 860145 NOC2L
```

This output is for the first three lines but is desired for the entire set.

The number of names in each line are not fixed, please keep that point in mind (it can be 1 or 5 or 10 or 20 names)

```
What I thought
```

use sed -i .bak to place the names one below the other along with the value in first three columns.

But in the end it became overly complicated.

Could you please think of a simpler way to get around this?

Thank you

Comment: You say you want the first 3 columns as your output, but your desired output shows 4 columns...

Comment: Well, I meant," I want to arrange names one below the pother along with the values in first three columns". That is why 4 column output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$3,$i}' file
chr1 762440 762981 SAMD11
chr1 858932 859148 KLHL17
chr1 858932 859148 SAMD11
chr1 858932 859148 NOC2L
chr1 859786 860145 KLHL17
chr1 859786 860145 SAMD11
chr1 859786 860145 NOC2L
chr1 890663 891747 KLHL17
chr1 890663 891747 NOC2L
chr1 890663 891747 SAMD11
chr1 890663 891747 HES4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @line = split;
  for my $field (@line[3 .. $#line]) {
    say "@line[0 .. 2] $field";
  }
}

__END__
chr1 762440 762981 SAMD11 
chr1 858932 859148 KLHL17 SAMD11 NOC2L 
chr1 859786 860145 KLHL17 SAMD11 NOC2L
chr1 890663 891747 KLHL17 NOC2L  SAMD11  HES4
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash (100% internal commands)
I had this answer:

```
#!/bin/bash


while read ONE TWO THREE FOUR
do
    for ARG in $FOUR
    do
        if [ ${ARG:0:1} != "(" ]    #<-- filtering out args with parentheses
        then
            echo "$ONE $TWO $THREE $ARG"
        fi
    done
done <"/path/to/your/datafile"
```

but since you changed the question, this would also change the answer to:

```
#!/bin/bash


while read ONE TWO THREE FOUR
do
    for ARG in $FOUR
    do
        echo "$ONE $TWO $THREE $ARG"
    done
done <"/path/to/your/datafile"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @data = split" ",$_;
    my $prefix = join" ",@data[0..2];
    for(3 .. $#data) {
        next if $data[$_] =~ /\([-+]?\d+\)/;
        say $prefix, " ", $data[$_];
    }
}

__DATA__
chr1 762440 762981 SAMD11 (-98410)
chr1 858932 859148 KLHL17 (-36927), SAMD11 (-2081), NOC2L (+35639)
chr1 859786 860145 KLHL17 (-36001), SAMD11 (-1155), NOC2L (+34713)
```

**output:**

```
chr1 762440 762981 SAMD11
chr1 858932 859148 KLHL17
chr1 858932 859148 SAMD11
chr1 858932 859148 NOC2L
chr1 859786 860145 KLHL17
chr1 859786 860145 SAMD11
chr1 859786 860145 NOC2L
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the Python tag as well, here's how I would do it in Python (reading input from either stdin or files on the command line, and writing output to stdout).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    parts = line.strip().split()
    first_three = " ".join(parts[:3])

    for code in parts[3:]:
        print("{first_three} {code}".format(first_three=first_three, code=code))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/^/\
/
t b
: b
s/\(\n\)\(\([^[:blank:][:cntrl:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{3\}\)\([^[:blank:][:cntrl:]]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([^[:blank:][:cntrl:]][^[:cntrl:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*$/\1\2\4\1\2\5/
t b
s/^\n//' YourFile
```

treat each line, expanded any last argument. First `t b` could be removed but it reset the test by security

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\S+\s+){3})(\S+)\s+(\S+)/\1\3\n\1\4/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Read in your file:

```
my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";
```

Split each line on a space (although if your data is tab delimited I would recommend `split(/\t/)`;

```
while (<$input>){
    my @split = split(/\s+/);
    print "$split[0]\t$split[1]\t$split[2]\t$split[3]\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
chr1    762440  762981  SAMD11
chr1    858932  859148  KLHL17
chr1    859786  860145  KLHL17
chr1    890663  891747  KLHL17
chr1    896072  896354  NOC2L
chr1    954920  955343  HES4
chr1    1195296 1195488 PUSL1
chr1    1243975 1244505 UBE2J2
chr1    1284370 1284709 ACAP3
chr1    1373711 1374872 CCNL2
```

Comment: I don't understand how it works for the OP but it leaves without printing from fifth field to the end.

Comment: Yes I agree, i re tested it with a small set of data. it works only partially :( chr1 762440 762981 SAMD11   
chr1 858932 859148 KLHL17 SAMD11 NOC2L 
chr1 859786 860145 KLHL17 SAMD11 NOC2L 
chr1 890663 891747 KLHL17 NOC2L SAMD11 HES4
chr1 896072 896354 NOC2L KLHL17 SAMD11 HES4

Comment: @FlyingFrog Its OK to select an answer, but requester should alwasy wait some time.  It may show up an better answer.

Comment: It depends on how each column is separated, and if the data in each column contains spaces.

Comment: chr1 762440 762981 SAMD11 chr1 858932 859148 KLHL17 SAMD11 NOC2L chr1 859786 860145 KLHL17 SAMD11 NOC2L chr1 890663 891747 KLHL17 NOC2L SAMD11 HES4 chr1 896072 896354 NOC2L KLHL17 SAMD11 HES4